# Pagamento máximo e minimo

Tags: sql, select

Tenho duas tabelas, `customers` e `payments`, quero verificar de cada cliente qual foi o maior e o menor pagamento que cada um fez.
Fiz esse SQL, mas não deu certo, alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
SELECT c.customerName, max(p.amount), min(p.amount)
FROM customers c, payments p 
WHERE p.customerNumber = c.customerNumber 
ORDER BY c.customerNumber
```

Comment: só pra constar, o nome das tabelas estão em portugues ou ingles?

Comment: Qual o erro que retornou? Esta falando a clausula GROUP BY.

Answer (score 2):

Falta adicionar a clausula GROUP BY no seu SELECT.

```
SELECT c.customerName, max(p.amount), min(p.amount)
FROM customers c, payments p 
WHERE p.customerNumber = c.customerNumber 
GROUP BY c.customerNumber
ORDER BY c.customerNumber
```

Outra forma que você pode fazer é utilizando JOIN:

```
SELECT c.customerName, max(p.amount), min(p.amount)
FROM customers c
JOIN payments p ON p.customerNumber = c.customerNumber
GROUP BY c.customerNumber
ORDER BY c.customerNumber
```